# Algorithm to generate pseudorandom numbers serie, reproducible knowing initial seed

Tags: python, algorithm, numbers, generator, series

I have to write a lightweight algorithm to generate pseudorandom infinite numbers series, and strongly dependant by initial seed.

In python it should be like

```
seed = 3345                 // Common number
generator = numgen(seed)
while True:
    generator.getNext()     // With the same seed it produce same numbers
```

As I wrote, with same seed it has to produce the same number series, even in different machines and in different times. Is there a standard patten for this or do I have to implement my own algorithm?

Comment: *Any* further requirements? Otherwise, I'd suggest `itertools.count`...

Comment: If your infinite series doesn't have to be random, why not use something stupidly simple like +1? (if the seed is 5, then the series is 5, 6, 7, ...) - or any other simple arithmetic function for that matter?

Comment: Trivially `def numgen(x): yield x` is infinite, non-random, strongly dependent on seed, and always works the same. Also, use `next` with generators (there's no `getNext`)

Comment: @Elad: I claim to have found the most stupid one :)

Comment: @dancek: This will only yield the seed once and then raise `StopIteration`.

Comment: @Sven: my bad, though I was more joking than answering :)

Comment: @Sven-Marnach indeed you have. +1

Comment: @Emilio: Do you really need to write your own [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRNG)?  Why not simply use one of the many that already exist?

Comment: I had some doubt using programming-language implementation, but actually i can implement some common mathematic algorithm. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the given requirements, you can go for the constant series

```
generator = itertools.repeat(seed)
```

This is

- lightweight
- not necessarily random
- strongly dependant on the initial seed
- produces the same series even on a different machine

**Edit**: To make this an actual answer, here is how to use Python's Mersenne Twister to generate a series of random numbers:

```
seed = 3345
maximum = 1000000
generator = random.Random(seed)
while True:
    print generator.random(maximum)
```

Creating your own `random.Random` instance ensures that no calls to the random number generator from elsewhere interfere with your random state.

Comment: Repeating the same number is not enough. I need some sort of variation in the number generation.

Comment: @Emilio: The main point of this answer and all the comments is that you need to specify what exactly your requirements are.  For example, you could tell us what you need the series for.  If the only additional requirement is "not constant", then simply start counting at the seed.  If this again is not what you are looking for, please specify what you need.

Comment: +1 for explaining about random.Random instance. The official docs don't cover that very well.